# Can't upload zip or rar files in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

Can't upload rar files in **Drupal 7** *file upload* field in a content type.its showing an error

> The specified file sample.rar could not be uploaded. Oops, looks you have uploaded a corrupted file. We do not allow such things here. We are a professional website!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to upload another rar?

Comment: @bub ys i have tried several other rar files.bt not working

Comment: check your permission to tmp folder and files folder.